# undefined method `reviews_path' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am building a method in which users can review other users and I am using https://github.com/mackenziechild/movie_review as a base

views/profiles/show

```
    <%= link_to "Write a Review", new_user_review_path(@user) %>
```

views/review/._form

```
   <%= form_for([@user, @review]) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <div id="star-rating"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

class Review < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :user

end


class ReviewController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    @review = Review.new
end

def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)

    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.receiver_id=@user.id
    @review.save
end

private

    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end
def review_params
```

How do I solve this?

Routes

```
user_review_index_path  POST    /users/:user_id/review(.:format)    
review#create

new_user_review_path    GET /users/:user_id/review/new(.:format)    
review#new
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :users do 

   resources :review, only: [:new, :create] 

end
```

hmm, maybe I have to do a member do?

Edit, I was playing around with it, I think it's because the model being reviewed is not being set properly in the controller

```
def set_receiver
  @review.receiver = User.find(params[:receiver_id])
end
```

Adding something like this gives me a "no resource found" error

How do I set the receiver of the review since it's another user?

Comment: What's the exact error? Is the review created or create fails?

Comment: The review is not created

Comment: Please share the backtrace too...save the review with bang and you will get the validation errors it is rolling back for `.save!`

Comment: The main problem is that you are calling `.save` and not actually checking if the record was saved or not. You always want a conditional in your save and update methods which checks if the record was created/updated and sends the appropriate response. Try using `rails g scaffold` as it will show you how a to create a conventional rails controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off your naming is totally backwards and confusing. If your app is focused on creating reviews of users `review.user` should point to the user that is the subject of the the review - not the author!

I would set the model up as so:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user # the subject
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User' # self explainatory
end
```

With that fixed it becomes a lot easier to untangle and reason about the code.

You´re also using the wrong pluralization in your routes:

```
resources :users do 
  resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create] 
end
```

In REST resources are in plural (unless its the rare case where the there can only be one resource).

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_user, only: [:new, :create, :index]
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users/:user_id/reviews/new
  def new
    @review = @user.reviews.new
  end

  # POST /users/:user_id/reviews
  def create
    @review = @user.reviews.new(review_params) do |r|
      r.author = current_user
    end
    if @review.save
      redirect_to @user, success: 'Thank you for your review!'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def set_review
    @review = @user.reviews.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

`app/views/reviews/new.html.erb:`

```
<%= form_for([@user, @review]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="star-rating"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It looks good, but I am getting ActionController::UnknownFormat in ReviewsController#new

Comment: ActionController::UnknownFormat means that you are sending the request as wrong format. Have you added `remote: true` to the form for example? Then you need to make sure the action responds to `js`.

Comment: I have added the remote: true to the form, no changes

Comment: hold on I fixed that issue, it was because of plurization

Comment: uninitialized constant Review::Author, odd, isn't it declared in the model? Does Author need to be declared in reviewParam?

Comment: My bad you have to specify the class_name since it can't be derrided from the name of the association `belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'`

Comment: And on the inverse side in the User model `has_many :reviews, foreign_key: 'author_id'` you need to tell it which column on reviews points back.

Comment: neither seem to work, can I push @author directly into the database table? Or better yet just push current_user.id, I don't think author needs a class does it?

Comment: I made a slip up though - make sure its `belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'`